# How to stub controller parameters when testing partial which invokes a route method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I want to test a partial component of my view. The partial is in `app/views/shared`. The partial invokes route methods to dynamically add links. For instance for my magazines and ads paths this is as follows:

```
 /magazines/a/ads/1

 magazine_ad_path(magazine_id: 'a', id: 1)
```

The nice thing about Rails is, that the current controller has all the current identifier you need.

```
> params
=> {'action' => 'show', 'controller' => 'ads', 'id' => '1'}
```

Which means, it is sufficient to just invoke `magazine_ad_path(id: 2)` to simply switch to another ad. This works all very well, but I don't know how to stub these parameters when I am writing my RSpec test for this partial.

In the test I invoke `render :partial`, but since there is no controller context with the parameters, the missing identifier are not completed.

How can I stub this in this case?

Comment: Please add actual code, I have no idea what you're talking about.